# Specify cell numeric format per row in Kendo Grid

Tags: kendo-grid

I have a Kendo Grid with a list of products and their respective amounts. Each product may have a different decimal precision, but I don't know how to reflect this in the Grid. As far as I can figure out, it is only possible to set the format for the entire column.

Currently, with format as `{0:n2}`, the Grid will display as:

```
PRODUCT       AMOUNT    PRECISION
Product A      10,00            0
Product B      10,00            2
Product C      10,00            3
Product D      10,00            1
```

While the desired result would look like:

```
PRODUCT       AMOUNT    PRECISION
Product A         10            0
Product B      10,00            2
Product C     10,000            3
Product D       10,0            1
```

Is it even possible to specify a different format for each row in Kendo Grid?

Comment: With the use of column data templates, it is possible, but you need to write some more code. For the data template on the Amount column, you can check the precision, and set the format based on the precision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to solve it by defining a template for the column, as gitsitgo suggested in the comments.

On the bound column, using C# and Razor, I specified the following template:

```
@<text>@item.Amount.ToString("F" + item.Precision, formatProvider)</text>
```

Where `formatProvider` is a reference to an IFormatProvider, holding the current CultureInfo.

Comment: Good stuff following up on your own question, glad it worked out!